# Common point in an array of rectangles

Tags: python, class, loops, oop

I am creating a program that involves a rectangle class, as well as a point and canvas class. One of the smaller functions asked of us is a common point function which determines if the canvas at hand has a common point throughout its array of rectangles. I am getting a list index error but i cannot see why.

Here is the common point function:

```
def common_point(self):
    '''(Rectangle) -> Boolean
    Returns True if rectangles in canvas all ahare a common point'''
    common = False
    for i in range(len(self.data)):
        for j in range(len(self.data),-1,-1):
            if self.data[i].intersects(self.data[j]) == True:
                common = True
            else:
                return False
    return common
```

and here is the intersect function it is calling:

```
def intersects(self,other):
    '''(Rectangle, Rectangle) -> Boolean
    Returns True if the two Rectangles intersect'''
    return not(self.p2.y < other.p1.y or self.p1.y > other.p2.y or self.p2.x < other.p1.x or self.p1.x > other.p2.x)
```

any help as to why would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the error message? Does it specify a line number?

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom     if self.data[i].intersects(self.data[j]) == True:
IndexError: list index out of range is the error it reads

Comment: The answer below explains it. The starting range is too high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range(len(self.data),-1,-1)` returns a list with length of `len(self.data) + 1`. This will always result in an index error when iterating using that range.

I suspect what you want is:

```
for j in range(len(self.data) - 1, -1, -1):
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured I was close, thank you none the less!